# Dropdown.js not working on bootstrap menu

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just started working with bootstrap. I have a test page here: http://devshed.atbashservices.com/TimeTracker/ViewEditCustomers.aspx

It has the following menu system.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Jobs <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Find Job</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Create Job</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">View/Edit Jobs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Customers <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Find Customer</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Create Customer</a></li>
                <li><a href="ViewEditCustomers.aspx">View/Edit Customer</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Billing Types <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Find Billing Type</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Create New Billing Type</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">View/Edit Billing Type</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Jobs <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Find a Job</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Create New Job</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The dropdowns aren't working. But the scripts are being referenced like the documenation says.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for some boostrap.min.js file in your code and couldnt find any.

Comment: I had placed it in the footer of the master page. I wonder if the master page isn't being referenced correctly.

Comment: I used Chrome Developer tools to browse linked files and there was no JS file. I dont know what back-end you are using or some layouting engine but it clearly didnt pass the js file:]